# Use Excel cell value in body of mailto hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, input, cells, mailto

In excel I have some cells that contain input for a e-mail form.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| E-mail | me@myemail.com |
| Subject | Input form |
| Name | John |
| Country | Poland |
| Body | Hello,%0D%0A My name is : B3 %0D%0A I'm from : B4 |
|  | Send E-mail |

In Cell B6 (Send E-mail) I have this formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&B1&"?Subject="&B2&"&body="&B5&"")
```

I need help with cell B5 that contains the other cells. I don't know how to get the body output:

Hello,
My name is: John
I'm from: Poland

How can I achieve this?

(Also I want cell B6 to not display the formula but 'Send E-mail')

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&B1&"?Subject="&B2&"&body="&B5&", Send E-mail")
```

doesn't work. I think this is a small type error, but if you can help with that too would be great!

Comment: Double check the formulas you've pasted. I think you're missing some quote marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the body to a formula.

```
="Hello,%0D%0A My name is : "&B3&"%0D%0A I'm from : "&B4
```

And fix the quotes in your Send Email formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&B1&"?Subject="&B2&"&body="&B5,"Send E-mail")
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Put to B5 formula instead template of string:

`="Hello,%0D%0A My name is : " & B3 & " %0D%0A I'm from : "& B4`

In this case formula in B6 will be like as

`=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&B1&"?Subject="&B2&"&body="&B5;"Send E-mail")`

Comment: FYI: OP's locale uses commas to separate arguments, not semicolons.

Comment: @EngineerToast Yes, I saw it in his formulas. However, [*The comma is the default list separator for US - English Locale*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/formula-errors#:~:text=The%20comma%20is%20the%20default%20list%20separator%20for%20US%20%2D%20English%20Locale.) contradicts *I'm from: Poland*

Comment: Sure, but they posted a formula and it (tries to) use a comma as the separator. It's possible they copy/pasted it from somewhere and didn't write it themselves, meaning it could be they use semicolons in formulas. Regardless, my intent was to point it out for OP and future readers. I did not intend to suggest you correct your formula as it is not wrong.

Comment: @JohnSUN thank you for your answer. I use both versions US + European that makes it more difficult for me to learn. However, both codes (with semicolon or comma) keep showing the whole formula instead of the 'Send E-mail). As far as selecting answer I have to go with the quickest one because they are the same. Sorry about that.